# AVAudioPlayer returns success but no sound from device

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have a very simple app that I have built to test out AVAudioPlayer.  I have a 16s aif file that plays just fine on my Mac.  Put it in a simple app and ran on my iPhone but no sound.  Sending 'play' to the object returns success and audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying comes back with success after 16 seconds.  Still no sound.  Have checked the sound volume on the iPhone, just fine.  Have checked to make sure my AVAudioPlayer object has volume set at 1.0 - it does.  Can anybody help?

Here's my code

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Soothing" ofType:@"aif"];
NSURL *playURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
NSError *error;

self.myAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:playURL error:&error];
NSLog(@"About to play sound");

self.myAudioPlayer.delegate = self;
[self.myAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
bool success = [self.myAudioPlayer play];

if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to play file");
} else NSLog(@"Looks like it succeded");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK - got it figured out.  I had not configured the AVAudioSession for my app.  Did something very simple as follows (copied from Apple's example code):

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];
if (setCategoryError)
    NSLog(@"Error setting category! %@", setCategoryError);
```

Sound now plays - plus learned a lot about how to control playback through screen locks, etc., which will be valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you get anything from the error?

```
if(error) {
    NSLog( @"%@", [error localizedDescription] );
}
```