# AVAudioPlayer dose not play sound, gives error

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play an MP3 file, however I am having problems with my code. This is what I have:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

        if (!audioPlayer) {
            NSLog(@"localizedDescription : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            [audioPlayer play];
        }
```

and this is the error I am reciving

```
localizedDescription : The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)
```

How do I stop this from happening? I want to play my sound once then stop it, but it can't even start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably caused by the path being invalid.

Try building it as follows

```
NSString *soundPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audiofile" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL URLWithString:soundPath];
```

instead.

Also make sure that `audiofile.mp3` is included in the current target.

Comment: okay this kind of works. I dosnt give the error and it goes into the else part of the if statment. But I still donot hear any sound and I have checked and the sound is decinatly on and not muted..

Comment: You probably haven't configured an audio session. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532290/avaudioplayer-returns-success-but-no-sound-from-device

Comment: This is the wrong way to construct a URL. Use `+fileURLWithPath:` instead, or even better, `-[NSBundle URLForResource:…]`